# How to conditionally fetch user data based on logged-in state with SWR?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, next.js, swr

I am trying to set some UI state that is dependent on if a user is logged in. If a user is logged in, some state in the UI should reflect this.

I am using SSG to statically generate pages and SWR to fetch the user data. When I call my fetcher function and try to call my custom hook to check if the user is logged in, on the initial request, the user is undefined, but when I reload, the user is present.

Why is this the case? Is the fetcher function called before anything else and how can I fix this.

Basically, all I want is to SSG the `[parkCode].js` pages and fetch some user data to display user specific state.

Here is my code:

```js
// [parkCode].js
import checkUser from '../../hooks/checkUser'
import useSWR from 'swr'

export default function Park({parkCode})
  const user = checkUser()

const fetcher = async () => {
  const username = await user?.username
  console.log(username)

  try {
    const {data} = await API.graphql({
      query: listSites,
      variables: {
        filter: {
          code: {eq: parkCode},
          owner: {eq: username},
        },
      },
    })

    return data?.listSites?.items[0] || null
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Site not added by user', err)
  }
}

  const {data, error} = useSWR('park', fetcher)
  console.log(data) // logs an error (says

}
```

My hook to see if a user is logged in

```js
//checkUser.js
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {Auth, Hub} from 'aws-amplify'

export default function checkUser() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    checkUserAuth()
    const unsubscribe = Hub.listen('auth', () => checkUserAuth())
    return () => unsubscribe()
  }, [])
  async function checkUserAuth() {
    try {
      const signedInUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      setUser(signedInUser)
    } catch (err) {
      setUser(null)
    }
  }
  return user
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the page is first rendered, the `user` variable still has its initial state (`null`), as the `checkUser` hook `useEffect` hasn't run yet. This means that when `useSWR('park', fetcher)` is called, the `user` inside the fetcher method will also be `null`. To prevent this behaviour, you can [conditionally fetch](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/conditional-fetching) the data in the `useSWR` call only when the `user` is set.

```js
export default function Park({ parkCode })
    const user = checkUser()

    const fetcher = async () => {
        // No need to call `await` to get `username` here
        const username = user?.username

        try {
            const { data } = await API.graphql({
                query: listSites,
                variables: {
                    filter: {
                        code: { eq: parkCode },
                        owner: { eq: username },
                    }
                }
            })

            return data?.listSites?.items[0] || null
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Site not added by user', err)
        }
    }
    
    // Only call the fetcher method if `user` exists
    const { data, error } = useSWR(user ? ['park', user?.username] : null, fetcher)
    
    if (data) {
        // Handle `data` when it's set
    }

    // Rest of your component
}
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense. I'll still grappling with how SWR works with SSG and SSR and what methods to use when.